# MCore(Arduino) - Python bluetooth communication

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, mbot

Pc and Mcore with bluetooth module are paired. The port is COM9 outgoing in PC. However, when I send message Arduino does not get anything. I just disconnect arduino from pc and write simple code in Mcore that turn on LED when input message is 1. However still nothing. These are the codes in python and arduino side:

```
import time
import serial

port="COM9"          #This will be different for various devices,COM port.
bluetooth=serial.Serial(port, 9600)         #Start communications with the bluetooth unit
bluetooth.flushInput()      #This gives the bluetooth a little kick
bluetooth.write(b'1')       #These need to be bytes not unicode
bluetooth.close()          #Otherwise the connection will remain open until a timeout
```

Arduino code:

```
char a;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
if(Serial.available()){a = Serial.read();}

if (a == '1'){
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }

  else{   
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);}

  delay(100);
}
```

I have tried to install Pybluez for WIN10, however, there was error. Do you think that this is the reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: first I would remove the `else` part to debug

Comment: I also increased delay much like 3 seconds, still no response. From the led of bluetooth module it is felt that it receives something, but either format is problem or maybe it is not working properly.

Comment: I have tried many combinations including your suggestion.

Comment: I can't add the comment that's why add an answer. Check this link and you will get your result. https://github.com/huberf/Computer-to-Arduino-Bluetooth

Comment: Thank you all for answers, but the reason was very simple: The baud rate of Mbot bluetooth was 115200 and hence it could not get proper data.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you never called `bluetooth.open()`.

What would be much easier to do is use [pySerialTransfer](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/pySerialTransfer) and [SerialTransfer.h](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/SerialTransfer) to guarantee reliable and robust serial communication between Python and your Arduino.

pySerialTransfer is pip-installable and cross-platform compatible. SerialTransfer.h runs on the Arduino platform and can be installed through the Arduino IDE's Libraries Manager.

Both of these libraries have highly efficient and robust packetizing/parsing algorithms with easy to use APIs and come with examples.

Answer (score 0):

kindly add a serial print before the if statement(`if (a == '1')`) to see what value of a is recieved so we can debug it